# Comma with "dass" to introduce clause after "sein"

Tags: comma, subordinate-clause

> An advantage of learning German is that Germany is doing well economically.

I would translate it as

> Ein Vorteil vom Deutschlernen ist, dass es Deutschland wirtschaftlich gut geht.

Is the comma in front of *dass* correct or not?

Comment: It's correct...

Comment: The sentence is grammatically correct, but I don't think I agree on the content. Would you only learn a language because the country in which it is spoken does economically well??

Comment: @PMF Thanks for your comment. I was just saying that it's one reason (among many other reasons)

Comment: Yes the comma is correct and also the sentence is proper German. However allow me to make to small remarks: 
1) you switched from the good verbal style in English to the not so great nominal style in German (all I want to say is that you made learning into a Non which would be more like "The leaning of German"). So I would suggest "Ein Vorteil Deutsch zu lernen ist, ..."
2) If you really want to be elegant and keep the nominal style I think you would need a Genitiv here: "Ein Vorteil des Deutschlernens ist, ..."
I hope that wasn't too picky.

Comment: @Magellan88 Thanks! That's very helpful (and not too picky at all.)

Comment: Let me get even more picky than Magellan88. As the sentence stands, it indicates that learning german makes germany better off, economically. But you want to imply that it's advantegous to learn german, because the economy is good, _meaning you yourself might be better of when learning german_. Notice how the last part is the actual advantage, that's possible because germany is doing well. A better way to say it would be 'Es ist vorteilhaft, Deutsch zu lernen, da es Deutschland wirtschaftlich gut geht.', therefore implying that there is an advantage (that isn't mentioned specifically).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You always have to put a comma before the *dass* conjunction because it indicates a dependent clause which cannot stand for itself (including the conjunction).

> Es ist schön, dass ich hier bin.

The only exception is when the clauses are actually compound by conjunctions that doesn’t require a comma, like *und* and *oder*:

> Es ist schön, dass ich hier bin und dass ich Spaß habe.

Also when the clauses are in reversed order you have to put a comma:

> Dass das Komma gesetzt werden muss, wusste ich.

… or in your case:

> Dass es Deutschland wirtschaftlich gut geht, ist ein Vorteil vom Deutschlernen.

The reversed form is often used when you want to enumerate different statements:

> Dass es Deutschland wirtschaftlich gut geht, ist ein Vorteil vom Deutschlernen. Ein weiterer Vorteil ist die Tatsache, dass es sich um eine der wichtigsten Sprachen Europas handelt.

Comment: *Vom Deutschlernen* is an inferior replacement to a genitive construction, which may be acceptable in conversation, but can't be recommended in writing.

Comment: Then again, is _Deutschlernen_ even an acceptable substitution for the more elegant _Erlernen der deutschen Sprache_?